# Find occurences of domain extension in a string PHP

Tags: php, regex

Hi look to print out:

```
test.net
tralala.net
```

from the following PHP code :

```
$query = "test.net dssdsd.com tralala.net";
$a = preg_grep('/(.*?)\.net$/', $query);
print_r($a);
```

But it gives me blank

Any idea ?

Comment: What's your expected output?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`preg_match_all()`](http://php.net/preg_match_all), like this:

```
$query = "test.net dssdsd.com tralala.net";
preg_match_all('/\S+\.net\b/', $query, $matches);
print_r($matches[0]);
```

This [outputs](http://viper-7.com/UpB9nf):

```
Array
(
    [0] => test.net
    [1] => tralala.net
)
```